# Azure automated email notifications of errors in ApplicationLog

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-automation

I have an Azure cloud application / Webrole and Worker role. Our company has the need to receive automated logs via email for SOX compliance reasons.

Is there anything out of the box with Azure which allows me to automatically email / notify the support team of various log activities or even email the log entries themselves automatically? Or, do I have to write something to do this?

For example: In the "Audit Logs" anytime there is a Level of Warning or above, email support team.

Answer (score 2):

A couple good options:

- Most Cloud Service logs get written to Azure Storage - the [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk/) is perfect for creating a simple WebJob that can monitor the BLOBs and send you applicable notifications.
- [Application Insights has easily configurable alerts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-alerts/) that can monitor and notify you of issues with your application.